# clipboard.readText returning a numeric value instead of the text on the clipboard

Tags: javascript

My first attempt at getting text from the clipboard resulted in the 'document not focused' error (not using DevTools) - then managed to get to it returning '[Object Promise]' and now it returns '2' (which is not the text on the clipboard). I have tried every which way but drunk to get this to work and it's probably a combination of some of the failed attempts. Any pointer will be appreciated.

I have noticed that using setTimeout stops the 'document not focused' problem, but there is not a three second delay.

```
async function readClipboard() {
try {
     const myText = setTimeout(async()=>(await navigator.clipboard.readText()), 3000); 
     alert(myText); 
          } catch(err) {
     alert(err); 
         } 
 }
readClipboard();
```

This returns 'undefined' and if I give the variable a text value (xxx) it just returns that not the clipboard text!

```
async function readClipboard() {
var myText // = 'xxx';

try {
    setTimeout(async()=>(myText = await navigator.clipboard.readText()), 3000); 
    alert(myText); 
    
} catch(err) {

    alert(err);
```

}

```
}


readClipboard();
```

Comment: If the original problem was “document not focused”, did you try `window.focus()`? setTimeout returns instantly with the timer id and doesn’t do anything related to the window focus.

Comment: I did use .focus on both the element and the window - still came back with the same error.

Answer (score 2):

> now it returns '2' (which is not the text on the clipboard) ?

Because `setTimeout` returns only its **timeoutID** which is passed to `clearTimeout`.

I don't know why you are using that, instead you can have it directly on listener.

```
const copy = document.getElementById('copy');
const clipboard = document.getElementById('clipboard');

copy.onclick = async () => {
  try {
    await navigator.clipboard.writeText('test');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
  }
}

clipboard.onclick = async () => {
  try {
    let data = await navigator.clipboard.readText();
    alert(data || "Please copy some text");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
  }
}
```

Html (Only works when `document` is focused)

```
<button id ='copy'>Copy something for test</button>

<button id='clipboard'>Get Cliboard Data</button>
```

Comment: Yuvaraj - thanks for your response. This is part of an auto-entry for a form. According to the ID it will return a Word document from the backend DB copy it to the clipboard and enter into a RichText area. All the other areas of the form I have managed with element.value. I have been through so many iterations of this it's driving me bonkers. I have marked the answer up as I try to figure it out.